# Getting error "module: identifier already required in doc" when importing code

Tags: racket, require

In my Racket program, I get the error message: "module: identifier already required in doc" when I try to require code from a file that I've written. But when I copy and paste the code into the requiring module, it works fine. Ideas?

I've tried using (provide (all-defined-out)) as well as listing all of the functions names in the provide form. By the way, I'm coding this in Scribble files rather than straight Racket files.

```
@(require racket/date
          racket/file
          racket/string
          racket/list
          racket/function
          racket/format
          db
          "directories.scrbl"
          "model-files.scrbl"
          )
```

Note that all the imports work fine from the directories.scrbl file, but the problem happens when I require model-files.scrbl.

Update: It's definitely a problem with Scribble. I changed all the code to Racket code from Scribble and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

`#lang scribble/base`, `#lang scribble/manual`, and `#lang scribble/doc` automatically provide `doc`. Therefore, when you unconditionally `require` two Scribble documents, `doc` is collided.

There are two ways to solve this problem.

1. Use [`only-in`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._only-in%29%29) or [`except-in`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._except-in%29%29) to control what should be `require`d. For instance, you can write:

   ```
   (require (except-in "directories.scrbl" doc)
            (except-in "model-files.scrbl" doc))
   ```

   This would require everything from `directories.scrbl` and `model-files.scrbl` except `doc` from both of them.
2. But as far as I know, it's very uncommon (and unidiomatic) to `require` a Scribble file directly. The better way is to restructure by creating a Racket file named `utils.rkt` and put the thing that you want to use in several Scribble files in `utils.rkt`, and then `(require "utils.rkt")` instead.

Comment: Thank you ! That's very clear, although I'm surprised that it's unidiomatic to require Scribble files directly.

Comment: The idea is that a Scribble file describes a document. One document can import another by [include-section](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html#(form._((lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt)._include-section)))